# Enable & Disable button and change the status in modal if condition match in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a pop up window which have 5 buttons. On the bases of status I have to enable & disable button in pop up window(modal).5 Status are : MATCH , UNMATCH, ACK, UNACK, DISPATCHED and 5 buttons are MATCH, UNMATCH, ACK, UNACK, DISPATCHED.
**If status is ACK in pop up window then all 4 button should be disable except UNACK button & if user click on UNACK button , than ACK button should become enable and status should change to UNACK in pop up window without closing it, and UNACK button become disable**, same way if status is **DISPATCHED  then only MATCH & UNMATCH button is enable and rest 3 are disable and on click of MATCH button status should change to ACK from DISPATCHED** in pop up window and **how to change the status (ACK to UNACK) in pop up window on click of UNACK button**

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onMatch()" [disable]="isDisable" >MATCH</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onUnMatch()"[disable]="isDisable">UNMATCH</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onAck()" [disable]="isDisable">ACK</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onUnack()"[disable]="isDisable">UNACK</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onDispatched()"[disable]="isDisable">DISPATCHED</button>


ts file where i m writing condition for status
isDisable(){
   if(matchStatus === MATCH){
      return true
  } else (matchStatus === MATCH || ACK || UNACK || DISPATCHED) {
      return false
  }
}
```

i m not sure how to achieve this enable & disable functionality with change in status on click of button in pop window(modal) 
thanks in advance.

Comment: My suggestion would be to pass button status as argument to `isDisable` method then check it with currently selected eg. `this.matchStatus` and decide if it should be disabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've created simple stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-status

The idea is to create a mapping between status and every button status.

```
buttons = {
  button0_disabled: () => { return this.status !== 'status0' },
  button1_disabled: () => { return this.status !== 'status1' },
  button2_disabled: () => { return this.status !== 'status2' },
};
```

So every change of status will trigger the changing of buttons statuses.

I hope it helps.